# Run Python script every 10 seconds

Tags: python

I have a function to do some work. The code should repeat 130 million times.

Currently, I use Crontab to run a python script every 1 min. It takes too long a time, I want that this python script run when I run it the first time and keep repeating continuously until the work gets over. I want a 10 seconds break between 2 task. How can I do that?

Comment: if now you use cron, you could do a cycle in the shell script and sleep for 5 secs there. See [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/cron-every-5-minutes/) how to do it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try the [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) module

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Just run : `pip install schedule`

Comment: Can it run in the background.For example, I create a  do_my_job.py use your method,  on ssh cmd line run 'python do_my_job.py'，can I close the ssh terminal?

Comment: @jianbingMa This will help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/396654/how-to-run-the-python-program-in-the-background-in-ubuntu-machine

Comment: How is this an accepted answer? OP said 1 minute was too slow, so you recommended 10 minutes. Schedule is still cron and restricted to one minute.

Answer (score 11):

I think you should use this method:

```
import time

while True:
    # code goes here
    time.sleep(10)
```

Actually it's not correct to use `while True` since it causes an infinite loop. There should be a condition over there. But since you have not supplied enough data, I cannot actually do that.

Comment: I don't think so. Please check the question again and see what's OP wants.

Comment: 'and sleep 10 or less seconds'. This is what he wants. This function stops the execution of the code for a given time.

Answer (score 2):

One approach might be using threads, you run a thread every N seconds. Since the processing is assumed to be light that might be the solution.

```
t=threading.timer(10,function,[function_arguments])  #executes your_function every 10 seconds (example only)
while True:
    t.start()
```

Be aware that the drawback of this solution is that if function() takes more time to process than the seconds_parameter you'll probably concurrency  problems.

Comment: Is it only Python 2?

Comment: According to python docs it on 2.7 and 3.1

Comment: `>>> import threading
>>> threading.timer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    threading.timer
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'timer'`

Answer (score 1):

You can look into [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/). It's not very complicated to use. You have to schedule your process.

You can add required sleep time in the in your script.

```
import time

def job()
   # tasks of the script

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        job()
        time.sleep(10)
```

The `job()` function will run in every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

how does the python thread get its work?
for instance if the stuff to work on is defined in some kind of list i would suggest the following approach:

```
import time
work = ["list", "of", "jobs", "here"]
for job in work:
    # do something with the job
    time.sleep(10)
```

this way the loop will exit as soon as there is no more work to do.

Comment: How do you know that the 'work' is a `list`? Can't it be a repetition operation?

Comment: because the wording of the origional question indicated that the work could run out - "It will always run until there is no work to do."

Comment: i made the assumption that if it could run out it must be some kind of queue/list/generator